# How do I make IntelliJ create Mocha debug configs when running unit tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js

When I create a new Mocha test file I am presented with the expected green gutter icons (▶ and ▶▶) to run each test or the suite. When I select "Run [test name]" I expect it to create a Mocha debug configuration and run it. Instead, IntelliJ creates a *NodeJS* run configuration, which understandably explodes in a shower of bit-flavored WTF.

If I manually create a configuration for the whole file, everything works as expected, including individual tests afterward. I am hoping that there is a setting somewhere that I have overlooked, something like "Settings -> ... -> Default Debug Configuration".

Does anyone know how I can make IntelliJ default to Mocha when a unit test is executed?

Answer (score 0):

The logic used for determining what test runner is available for a given test file is based on dependencies declarations in `package.json` nearest to current file. Do you have `'mocha'` listed as a dependency/dev dependency in your `package.json`? How many `package.json` files do you have in your project?
Note that, if Mocha is not installed locally/included in `package.json`, you can create a **Mocha** run configuration with `"All in directory"` selected and specify a directory where your spec files are located. In this case, clicking the gutter button in a test file inside this directory will suggest to run test with Mocha.

Note also that if you have created **Node.js** Run configuration with `"JavaScript file"` set to your mocha test file, IDEA will suggest using this configuration instead of Mocha when clicking on your tests, because explicitly created run configurations associated with current file have priority over the ones auto-generated from context. Deleting the configuration should solve the issue.